# How react-static-boilerplate make use of react's ref for mounting and umounting?

Tags: reactjs

I quite new to react. What is `ref={node => (this.root = node)}` for in:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigation from './Navigation';
import Link from '../Link';
import s from './Header.css';

class Header extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    window.componentHandler.upgradeElement(this.root);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.componentHandler.downgradeElements(this.root);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <header className={`mdl-layout__header ${s.header}`} ref={node => (this.root = node)}>
        <div className={`mdl-layout__header-row ${s.row}`}>
          <Link className={`mdl-layout-title ${s.title}`} to="/">
            Igene Logo Here
          </Link>
          <div className="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
          <Navigation />
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }

}

export default Header;
```

*( from [react-static-boilerplate (RSB)](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-static-boilerplate/blob/master/components/Layout/Header.js) )*

and it's relationship to mount and unmounting?

I get the concept of ref based on reading [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), but still find it quite hard to understand when it is used in RSB. Can someone enlighten me how it works and also it's relationship to the `componentDidMount()` and `componentWillMount()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following:

`ref={node => (this.root = node)}`

stores a reference to the DOM element that it is contained within.  Your example sees it inside a header tag, which makes it possible to then manipulate the *actual* DOM element of the header by referencing `this.root`.

One of the main use cases for storing refs is that the element becomes available to other members of the same component class.

Examples include:

- focusing on a particular form input within componentDidMount
- or disabling input into a text field after another one has been filled (these are examples are quite rough, but hopefully you get the idea).

Comment: thanks! But i also wanted to ask about window.componentHandler.upgradeElement/downgradeElement and why they need that node?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it's usage with window.componentHandler.upgradeElement/downgradeElement.